# How can I maximize a WPF page when the application starts?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a simple WPF application with two xaml Pages. I'd like the app opening with the maximum size of the screen.
I've found only answers about WPF Windows, but for Pages there is not a "WindowState" property.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your page a Window object? If WindowState doesn't exist in it, it sounds like it might not be... What is it, if that's the case?

Comment: It is a Page object.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243910/page-vs-window-in-wpf). Having a page as a main windows is not a good ideea. You can simply add a window and host the page inside it.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianFaciu, you gave me the right suggestion!

Answer (score 29):

In your Xaml window definition simply define:

```
WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `Width` and `Height` property manually according to your current Screen Resolution from here

```
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
System.Windows.SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
```