# What is the difference between a Window & a Page in WinUI?

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

I'm getting started with developig a new WinUI application and wanted to understand the different use-cases for the Window and Page elements? When should I use Page over Window & Vice Versa?

Comment: WPF, not UWP, but [Page vs Window in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243910/page-vs-window-in-wpf). I'd guess that, [since WinUI looks like it's drawing from WPF, WinForms, etc...](https://microsoft.github.io/microsoft-ui-xaml/about.html#what-is-it), the concepts should be the same.

Comment: If you ware making a native Windows application, you should use `Window`. If you are making a browser hosted application, use `Page`

Comment: The window is the "top-level container" of your app that you can drag around the screen, minimize, maximize and close. A `Page` is some UI that is hosted in the window.

Comment: I'm really not an expert but Windows are use in any order usually a bit like a tree where the main window is root. In pages, it is more like a phone app where pages are called one after the other like a browser (where you can always go back until you reah the main page). Usually with pages, a page cover a full application space all the times while in Window you can have Modeless Window wherew you can switch from to the other. There should be more diffs but I can't tell. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

When we refer to a Window in WinUI it is quite literally how it sounds, a desktop window. Whereas a page would be a page within that window that can be shown and hidden etc.

This makes sense when using a Frame and a Navigation View as you can then have the frame display the pages and change the frame according to what is selected in the navigation view and apply relevant transitions etc.

I didn't really get it at first but now using it, it makes so much more sense having strictly defined Windows and Pages.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: A Page is part of a Window]

> *A Page is just an optional component of a Window*

---

A **[Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.window?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4)** is the **main** UI **artifact** of your desktop app; it's your starting point, it's **mandatory**.

Within a window you compose your **UI** *(visual look and feel)* and **UX** *(user interaction and navigation between visuals)* by using various **controls** and **user controls**. So a window hosts controls and user controls that interact with each other based on user input.

---

A **[Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.page?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4)** is just a specific type of **[UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol?view=winrt-22621)** *(like **[Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.grid?view=winrt-22621)** or **[StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel?view=winrt-22621)**)* within a window *(displayed via a **[Frame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.frame?view=windows-app-sdk-1.4)** control)*, that **helps** you **with** the **navigation** part.

The best practice is to derive it and define specific pages for your app, like: `class HomePage : Page`, `class ClientsBrowsePage : Page`, `class AddClientPage : Page`, etc. through which you can then navigate. All part of the same window.

> *An app can have a multiple windows if it makes practical sense, but that's a completely different topic and it must be very well justified; from a usability perspective, it's preferable to stick to a single window.*

---

Therefore, unlike the Window, a Page **is optional**. Say you need to develop a single screen app, that needs no navigation. Using a Page in this case makes zero sense ‍♂️. Or maybe you want to develop your own custom navigation mechanism... again no need to use a Page.